# Customize AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayerViewController to play video in my application, 
I don't want to make the player from scratch.
is there a way to add some other extra UI components and functionality to the AVPlayerViewController?

```
class AVKitViewController: AVPlayerViewController {

    private let url =
        URL(string:
            "https://www.digikala.com/mag/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Call-of-Duty-Modern-Warfare-Story-Trailer.mp4")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let video = AVPlayer(url: url!)
        player = video

        player?.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller): Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

Comment: check out contentOverlayView property of AVPlayerViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to do such thing. the only way possible, is to use AVFoundation to create our own AVPlayer from scratch.